# Как открыть и прочитать файл в kernel module?

Tags: linux, c, kernel

Как открыть и прочитать файл из userspace директории в kernel module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1184346/4827341

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Помог вот этот пример (хотя раньше его видел, но почему-то пропустил):

```
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/fs.h> 
#include <linux/sched.h> 

static char* file = NULL; 
module_param( file, charp, 0 ); 

#define BUF_LEN 255 
#define DEFNAME "/etc/yumex.profiles.conf";  // произвольный текстовый файл 
static char buff[ BUF_LEN + 1 ] = DEFNAME; 

static int __init kread_init( void ) { 
    struct file *f; 
    size_t n; 
    if( file != NULL ) strcpy( buff, file ); 
    printk( "*** openning file: %s\n", buff ); 
    f = filp_open( buff, O_RDONLY, 0 ); 

    if( IS_ERR( f ) ) { 
        printk( "*** file open failed: %s\n", buff ); 
        return -ENOENT; 
    } 

    n = kernel_read( f, 0, buff, BUF_LEN ); 
    if( n ) { 
        printk( "*** read first %d bytes:\n", n ); 
        buff[ n ] = '\0'; 
        printk( "%s\n", buff ); 
    } else { 
        printk( "*** kernel_read failed\n" ); 
        return -EIO; 
    } 

    printk( "*** close file\n" ); 
    filp_close( f, NULL ); 
    return -EPERM; 
} 

module_init( kread_init );
```